# How to write page.tpl.php where the HTML files is more than one?

Tags: theming

I'm using Drupal 7 and trying to set my custom theme up.

I usually replace the `index.html` to `page.tpl.php`, then I change what I want it to be dynamic on my site. But now I have more than one HTML file which is about.html, blog.html and contact.html

Can anybody explain to me how to write that?

Comment: Please **edit** your question to provide more details about that "more than one HTML file", such as how these files relate to each other (or maybe there are like 5 pages, for 5 different pages of the website).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually you may have to create a page--front.tpl.php for index page of your website and a page.tpl.php to have all other pages.

you could also use theme debug mode too. it can be enabled by including the following in settings.php,

**$conf['theme_debug'] = TRUE;**

The ablove will include theme suggestions as html comments, that helps you theming your pages.

Comment: If I create a page--front.tpl.php for index.html how can I  crate page.tpl.php for contact.html, and blog.html . how can I writer  all of them in page.tpl.php

Comment: I think you need to understand basics of Dupal theming from drupal.org, [Theming] (https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming). 
Please go through Regions, Blocks, Templates etc.,

Comment: Thanks for your reply, can you guide me to a useful tutorial or some books for theming?

Comment: Drupal 8 Theming theoretically explained at, http://sqndr.github.io/d8-theming-guide/index.html 

For video tutorial I recommend the following,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9u0B1F650U

Answer (score 0):

Simply create a file with the name "page.tpl.php". Below is the structure of how a theme folder should look like:

[image: Custom theme structure]

For further details read [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/171194).